# How to load page until specific element found selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

Is there a way to set timeout when specific element in webpage loads

**Notice**: I am talking about loading webpage using `driver.get()` method

I tried setting page loads timeout to 10s for example and check whether element is present but if it is not present i'll have to load it from start.

**Edit**:

Clearly said that I don't want to load full url

I want `driver.get()` to load url until element found and then stop loading more from url

In your examples you used simply `driver.get()` method which will load full url and then execute next command. One way is to use `driver.set_page_load_timeout()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

op = Options()
op.page_load_strategy = 'none'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=op)
driver.get(URL)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, '//div')))
driver.execute_script("window.stop();")
```

PS. You will keep getting off-topic answers if you post vague questions without a line of code.

Comment: Complete off-topic

Comment: I edited it. Page load strategy is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

`webdriver` will wait for a page to load by default. It does not wait for loading inside `frames` or for `ajax` requests. It means when you use `.get('url')`, your `browser` will `wait` until the page is completely loaded and then go to the next command in the code. But when you are posting an `ajax` request, `webdriver` does not wait and it's your responsibility to `wait` an appropriate amount of time for the page or a part of page to load; so there is a module named `expected_conditions.`

Comment: Can you elaborate it more?

Comment: If I can't pass from `driver.get()` how should I use explicit wait

Answer (score 0):

When the element is not found you get an error so you can use " try " untill the element is found:

```
while True:
    try:
        element = driver.find_element(by=By.<Your Choice>, value=<Name or Xpath or ...>)
    except:
        time.sleep(1)
```

It tries till the element is found

Comment: Dude I am talking about `driver.get()` method, loading url - webpage understand!